# How to access webmap in ArcGIS Portal from Angular app on localhost

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, arcgis-portal, authentication, angular

I'm testing an Angular CLI application that's running on my PC at http://localhost:4200 and which needs to access a webmap hosted on an ArcGIS Enterprise Portal.

The typical method for doing so within the ArcGIS Server JavaScript API is:

```
EsriConfig.portalUrl = "https://url-to-portal";
const webMap: esri.WebMap = new EsriWebMap({
    portalItem: {
      id: "webmap-item-id"
    }
});
```

This is failing for me with a CORS error because the Portal security has been restricted to a particular domain:

[image]

> Access to fetch at 'https://url-to-portal/web/sharing/rest/portals/self?f=json&culture=en-gb' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

How can I access this webmap from my PC during development?

I tried to add my localhost to the list of approved domains on the Portal security page using all combinations of `localhost`, `http://localhost`, `http://localhost:4200`, `http://127.0.0.1` etc but they all return an error message from the Portal security page:

[image]

Alternatively, how can I try the "set the request's mode to 'no-cors'" suggestion within the ArcGIS Server JS API syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer came from Steven Haslemore via Twitter, which was to use the `--disable-web-security` flag on Chrome:

`chrome.exe --user-data-dir="C:/Chrome dev session" --disable-web-security`

This avoids the CORS error during testing.